# Authentication problem of my pipeline with my gitlab project

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am in multi-branch option with my jenkins and I have a problem of authentication to Gitlab. Here is my jenkins file :

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    environment {
    registry = "*****@gmail.com/test"
    registryCredential = 'test'
    dockerImage = ''
    }
    stages {

        stage('Cloning our Git') {
            steps{
                git 'https://gitlab.com/**********/*************/************.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Build docker image') {
            steps {  
                script {
                    dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy our image') {
            steps{
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry( '', registryCredential ){
                        dockerImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Cleaning up') {
            steps{
                sh "docker rmi $registry:$BUILD_NUMBER"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I got:
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://gitlab.com/************/*******/***************.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied

**I would like to know how to authenticate with the jenkinsfile to gitlab or if you have a better solution for me I am interested. Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the link provided in the error message, you end up here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html#troubleshooting

You need to create a **Personal Access Token** which is kind of a special ID to delegate access to parts of your account rights.

The documentation for PAT is here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

In the Gitlab repository interface, it is under `Settings > Access Tokens`.

As you try to read an HTTPS repository, it seems you need to create a token with rights `read_repository`.

Then you should be able to access the repository with:
`https://<my-user-id>:<my-pat>@gitlab.com/<my-account>/<my-project-name>.git`

Comment: You can also create username-password-credential and useit (remember: username == GitlabUserId and password == access-token)